# Angular 5 httpclient is supposed to return a mappable Observable. After the mapping I lose the observable. What is going on?

Tags: angular, observable

Angular 5 httpclient is supposed to return a mappable Observable. After the mapping, I lose the observable. What is going on? Am I missing something here?

**The code**

```
  getRepos(org:string):Observable<any>{
    let params = new HttpParams().set('org',org);
    return  this.http.get(
      'https://us-central1-deployanywhere.cloudfunctions.net/github/repos',{params}
    ).map((ob:any)=>{

      return ob.data.map((o:any)=>{
        return {name:o.name,id:o.id}
      })
    })
  }
```

My imports

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";
import {AngularFireDatabase,AngularFireList,AngularFireObject} from "angularfire2/database";
import {HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpRequest} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

[image]

Tried Adding  to the request. 
[image]

I'm using Typescript ~2.3.3.

Weird, so if I wrap everything in an observable it works fine. Can someone help explain this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what kind of data should be `ob` in your `.map((ob) =>...)`?

Comment: I think you just need to change `this.http.get(` to `this.http.get<any>(`.

Comment: @NoémiSalaün the returning data a github array that contains the users repos. This shouldn't be the issue right? The data looks like this {data:[{name:"name",id:"123"}]}

Comment: import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try such solution in this blog: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3

They proposed to wrap code in pipe and use catchError:

```
import { ajax } from "rxjs/observable/dom/ajax";
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
import { catchError, map } from "rxjs/operators";

const name = ajax
.getJSON<{ name: string }>("/api/employees/alice")
.pipe(
map(employee => employee.name),
catchError(error => of(null))
);
```

Once I did like this there wasn't an error any more

Comment: pay attention from where they import `map`, `of` and `catchError`

Comment: also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411594/observable-catch-is-not-a-function)