# Observable .catch is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I get this very annoying error when running my code from a unix environment. This works fine when I run the code locally through `ng serve`, But when I deploy the code to my server, this error halts all program execution:

> `ERROR TypeError: this.http.get(...).catch is not a function`

Google results state that I should import rxjs namespaces straight from their location, and not through the rxjs/Rx bundle, but I get this error regardless. Other results point out that I may have missed importing rxjs operators, but they are definitely included in my case.

I've even checked the included sourcemaps using DevTools, and the operators are included out to the browser.

Can anybody tell me why I'm getting this error? I'm using rxjs: ^5.5.2

**This is my code.**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  all(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('url')
      .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
  }
  handleError(error) {
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Based on @Jota.Toledo's comment below, I will provide the code using this method:

```
this.myService.all().subscribe(
  result => {
    this.isLoading = false;
    if (result) {
      this.clients = result;
    }
  },
  error => this.isLoading = false
);
```

Is giving two callback functions in subscribe like this, the same as "using the catch method somewhere before the operator is added"?

Comment: which version of rxjs you are using?

Comment: Edited the question @Aravind

Comment: are you sure that the problem was comming from this code snippet? the operator import is fine, most likely you are using the catch method somewhere before the operator is added

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I've edited the question providing the code using this service. Your comment also raises a new question...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `rxjs 5.5.2` you can solve this problem using lettable operator, in this case, `catchError`. You have to import it from `operators` like: `import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';`. In general, all operators must be imported in this way, same thing goes for `observable` like `observable/of`.

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

all(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>('url')
    .pipe(
        map(() => //do stuff),
        catchError((error: Error) => {
         //
        })
    )
}
```

Read more about lettable operators [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3?gi=2933859fdd18).

Comment: Your understanding is partially wrong. There is indeed a lettable version of the catch operator, called catchError, but the original still exists. In the same blog that you linked, there is an example that uses the old patch approach with no problems, and it matches OPs implementation. So refactoring OPs approach to use the new pipe method, doesnt really answers his question.

Comment: You are right. I proposed a way to solve it with lettable operators.